# GRASS not working with QGIS 2.18.28

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-7.6

apologies if asking a question that others have asked before, but I'm unable to find a solution.

I had to install QGIS 2.18.28 as I need to work with a custom plugin for 2.x versions.
This plugin requires also GRASS, but I keep receiving an error message that GRASS 7.6.0 is not working as it is not in the folder.

I tried, in order:

- reinstalling QGIS
- Installing GRASS standalone and OSGeo4W version and linking the QGIS plugin to their folder
- putting the .dll in the QGIS plugin folder

I have a working GRASS version now (7.6.1) in my desktop but I don't know how to make QGIS see it.

Can someone suggest a working solution?